# How to run menu options automatically in unix script

Tags: shell-script

I am new to UNIX and tried to create automation script as per my requirement but stuck up in the middle.please help on this.

Requirement:

```
           directory /usr/ab/bc contains two menus as test and test1.
```

currently doing manual as go to the directory /usr/ab/bc and type menu test and then test1

test and test1 contains options as:

```
a-activity query
b-access logs
c-console logs
q-Quit
```

then type option (a) which will call abc.sh script then type option (b) which will call act.sh and so on.. but my requirement is it possible to get the menus from the directory /usr/ab/bc  then execute one by one like first test menu and test1 menu and run the menu options sequentially which will call the corresponding shell script.

code which I tried:

```
   while true 
   do
   clear

  echo "Menu"

  echo "a- Run  Activity Query:"

  echo "b- Parse  Access Logs:"

  echo "c-Parse  Console Logs:"

  echo "d- Access Logs:"

  echo "q-Quit:"


    read answer 

   case $answer in
    a) cd /xx/yy/tt/cmd/
      sh ./act.sh

      break        
      ;;

       b) cd /xx/yy/tt/cmd/

          sh ./bct.sh uuu

         break  
        ;;

       c) cd /xx/yy/tt/cmd/

          sh ./cty ttt

          break
          ;;


        q) Quit ;;

     esac
     done
    done
```

Thanks in advance please help on this

Answer (score 0):

My experience is sad using tools seem :
Whiptail  or    dialog is better for making menu

For more info see:

https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting/Whiptail

For dialog :

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_adv_dialog.php